# Updating the mysql database based on user input

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to insert the selected status timestamps in the corresponding column which user has chosen from the menu.
**Brief explanation**
Start from the database i have created columns like snap below.
[image]
Initially user will insert the sonumber and status, Now i need database to update current time and date in the database, remaining column initialized to zero.
Next user will select update option, here user will enter so-number as well as new status(from dropdown). Now i need database to update the new status with current time and store in the particular status column.

Starting with insert page saved as "insert.html" and "insert.php" Respectively

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="insert.php" >
<p>
<lable>ENTER SO NUMBER</lable>
<input type="text"  name="soid" id="soid" maxlength="6" required>


<p>
<lable>SELECT DEPARTMENT</lable>
<select type="text"  name="dept" id="dept">

<option value="NGS Analysis">NGS Analysis</option>
<option value="E-Array">E-Array</option>
<option value="Micro-Array">Micro-Array</option>
<option value="NGS Data">NGS Data</option>


</select>
</p>

<p>
<lable>SELECT STATUS</lable>
<select type="text"  name="status" id="status">

<option value="Sample Recived">Sample Recived</option>
<option value="Mol Bio Extraction">Mol-Bio Extraction</option>
<option value="Extraction QC">Extraction QC</option>
<option value="Library Prep">Library Prep</option>
<option value="Library QC">Library QC</option>
<option value="Sequencing">Sequencing</option>
<option value="Data check">Data Check</option>
<option value="Re-Sequencing">RE-Sequencing</option>
<option value="QC Check">QC Check</option>
<option value="Analysis Started">Analysis Started</option>
<option value="Analysis Completed">Analysis Completed</option>
<option value="Report">Report</option>
<option value="Outbound">Outbound</option>
</select>
</p>



<p><button><img src="http://brandonmadeawebsite.com/images/art/icons/insert_icon.png"  height="50" />INSERT</button></p>
</form>
```

insert.php

```
<?php


 $so = $_POST['soid'];

 $dp = $_POST['dept'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "status";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO $dbname.statusinfo (soid, dept ) VALUES ( '$so','$dp')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
echo "Inserted sucessfully with So Number <u><b>$so</b></u> Corresponding Status is <u><b>$st</b></u>";


$conn->close();

?>
```

Now below update script which is saved as "update.html","update.php" respectively

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" name="form2">
<p>
<lable>ENTER SO NUMBER</lable>
<input type="text"  name="soid" id="soid" required>

<p>
<lable>SELECT STATUS</lable>
<select type="text"  name="status" id="status">

<option value="Sample Recived">Sample Recived</option>
<option value="Mol Bio Extraction">Mol-Bio Extraction</option>
<option value="Extraction QC">Extraction QC</option>
<option value="Library Prep">Library Prep</option>
<option value="Library QC">Library QC</option>
<option value="Sequencing">Sequencing</option>
<option value="Data check">Data Check</option>
<option value="Re-Sequencing">RE-Sequencing</option>
<option value="QC Check">QC Check</option>
<option value="Analysis Started">Analysis Started</option>
<option value="Analysis Completed">Analysis Completed</option>
<option value="Report">Report</option>
<option value="Outbound">Outbound</option>


</select>
</p>

<p><button><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/32/User-Interface-Available-Updates-icon.png"  height="50" /> UPDATE</button></p>
</form>
```

update.php

```
<?php
 $so = $_POST['soid'];
 $st = $_POST['samplerecived'];
 $st1 = $_POST['molbioextraction'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "status";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}
   switch ($st):

case $st:$result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE statusinfo SET `samplerecived`= CURTIME()  WHERE soid='$so' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    break;
case $st1:$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE statusinfo SET  `molbioextraction`= CURTIME() WHERE soid='$so' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    break;
echo "Updated sucessfully with So Number $so Current Status is set to $st ";

  $conn->close();

   ?>
```

Kindly help me to do so, if you guys need any more information feel free to ask.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are the scripts failing? what have you tried to remedy that?

Comment: its updating all column at once, but i need only that column to update which user has selected

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: no data is required sir, just u enter some number in SO-Number field

Comment: It is, if the query is misbehaving and SQL isn't throwing an error then the problem is between your query and SQL. In order to find out why we must  be able to replicate the problem outside of PHP, fix it, then migrate the changes into your PHP script. a `DESCRIBE` of your table will also help. If you aren't willing to share any data with us, confirm that the query works as intended in a SQL browser.

Comment: Do you mean all columns are populated with a timestamp? Does this happen as soon as you insert the record, or really only on updates? If the former, the default values of all columns not specified in the insert query is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, so this behaviour would be rather expected?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you only need the user selected fields to be inserted and the other to be either NULL or some default value.

You have the default value for all the fields set as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. This is why all the fields are being assigned a default value of the current timestamp. Remove the default value, allow them to be NULL (or set some default value other than `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) and your problem will be solved.